# Can you premake mojitos?

Tags: drinks

I work at a busy bar and every Thursday we have mojitos for $5. I am curious if there is some sort of way that we can pre make some of the drink to make the preparation easier and faster. 
Thanks!!!

Comment: See also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12560/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-extract-mint-flavor-for-a-mojito

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if having them pre-mixed would affect the flavor or not. One thing that could speed you up is having the limes already juiced. According to [Dave Arnold at Cooking Issues](http://www.cookingissues.com/2010/10/01/fresh-lime-juice-wtf/) people generally prefer lime juice after it has "aged" at least 4 hours. Maybe this changes with mojitos, it's hard to say.

This is assuming you are using fresh lime juice. Are you muddling fresh mint and sugar, or do you use simple syrup? You could perhaps make a mint syrup, then just throw a mint leaf on top as a garnish, that would save you some time.

Comment: You can definitely infuse mint into either syrup or alcohol and make mojitos from it, but you do have to be careful to get it right - it's definitely possible to extract components of the flavor besides what you get by muddling it.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine worked at a midtown NYC bar where they went through a lot of mojitos during happy hour. They would keep a large beverage dispenser [(like these)](http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/Search/Search.aspx/beverage-dispenser/_/N-?sstr=beverage%20dispenser&dim=1&nty=1&order_num=-1) full of all the ingredients already mixed up.

[image: beverage dispenser]

I think the key was that they would go through a lot of them quickly, so it was always pretty fresh. They would garnish with mint leaves, but I don't think they actually muddled each one separately. Many bars also sell pitchers of mojitos.

That said, I don't know if I would endorse this idea. Part of the experience of drinking a cocktail is watching a skilled bartender make it for you to order. That said, if you are muddling the mint and sugar in the same way, just in a larger volume, maybe using a large container and a large grinding tool, it might taste the same. Maybe use a set up like they use for making fufu in West & Central Africa.

[image]